# Report Folder - Edit Access to one specific user

Tags: reports-folder

I have a report folder, which has public read only access to a number of user groups. One of the users needs to have additional rights, i.e. edit rights for this folder. In the folder settings I cannot turn on additional rights. Is it possible to do this anywhere else?
Tia, Lily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign additional rights to a particular user by creating a permission set -> enable the editing/view all custom/public reports settings  -> add the related user to the permission set. This should be straight forward.